# Is it possible to Reset long accumulator at each partition in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, worker

I am trying to reset `longAccumulator` at each partition but unable to do so. I am trying in this way.

```
val list = (1 to 100).toList
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list,4)
val acc = sc.longAccumulator("1L")

rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(i,iterator) => 
acc.reset()
acc.add(iterator.sum)
iterator
}
```

Currently this code does not reset the accumulator at each partition. In the driver we can reset the accumulator to zero by calling the `reset()` method. I want to ask is it possible to reset accumulator at for each partition.

I have n number of partitions. I want to store sum of values at each partition in a `List`. For partition 0 its sum should be store on index 0 of list and so on.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want the sum of the values in each partition you shouldn't use an accumulator. What is your end goal here?

Comment: let i have n partitions. I want to store sum of values at each partition in a List. for partition 0 its sum should be store on index 0 of list and so on

Comment: In most situations what values are in which partition (or their sums) are uninteresting and prone to change. Are you sure that is what you actually need? What do you want to use them for? The reason I'm asking is that there probably exists better solutions depending on your end goal.

Comment: Please see this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361991/update-variables-at-worker-nodes-in-spark?noredirect=1#comment101214531_57361991 one is actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations what values are in which partition (or their sums) are uninteresting and prone to change. However, it's still possible to compute.

---

You do not want to use an accumulator to sum the values of each partition. Instead you can simly compute the sums and return them as a new RDD.

To get a list of the sums in partition order, return the index with the sum and sort with it. Then remove it.

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(i,iterator) => 
  Seq((i, iterator.reduce(_ + _))).toIterator
}.collect().sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

This will give you an array with the sums in order.

Answer (score 1):

According to your end-game, you might want to use a custom Map Accumulator.
Take a look at [this](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-records/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/swoop/spark/accumulators/ByKeyAdditiveAccumulator.scala). Use it as follows:

```
val myAcc = new ByKeyAdditiveAccumulator[Int, Long]
sparkContext.register(myAcc)
...
rdd.foreachPartition(partition => 
   acc.add((TaskContext.get.partitionId(), partition.size))
...
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val partitionCount = myAcc.value.asScala
```